# Adding elements with content not working in NStable view in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I created a tableview and added image & text table view cell designed it now i thought to add another label in the row and assigned some values to the label based on the rows but it is not working and one more problem i cant hide label when the label in cell while in view i can able to hide

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {

    NSImage *profile=[NSImage imageNamed:@"header_menubg.png"];

    NSString *identifer=[tableColumn identifier];
    if([identifer isEqualToString:@"Mainidentifier"])
    {
    cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];



    [cellView.textField setStringValue:[_homearray objectAtIndex:row]];

    [cellView.imageView setImage:profile];
        return cellView;


    }

    if(row==0)
{
 _countLabel.stringValue=@"40";
 [cellView.textField setHidden:YES];
}

    return nil;
```

}

And even i tried to hide text field in some rows that too not working what may be the problem

Comment: What exactly is cellView? It is never declared.